# Qt Creatorに既存のソースを取り込みたい

Tags: qt, qt-creator

今までIDEの使用経験がない、初心者です。ここ数ヶ月C++の課題に取り組んでいます。今まではMacOSのターミナル上でコンパイル、実行してきたのですがデバッグに時間がかかるためQt上で開発を進めようと思いました。ですが、Qtのプロジェクトのフォルダに.hと.cppを置いてビルドしても、原因のわからないトラブルが多発して、どうにも進まなくなっています。IDEを使うこと自体がはじめてですのでQt CreatorもしくはIDE一般を使う上で何かとっかかりとなるような入門書や資料などがあれば紹介していただきたいです。

---

お返事ありがというございます。 辿った手順を書いていきます。 
新しいプロジェクトを作成
↓
他のプロジェクト&empty qmake Projectを選択
↓
ディレクトリを指定したのちDesktop Qt 5.4.2 clang 64bitにだけチェックを入れて続きをクリック
↓
バージョン管理システムに追加でGitを選択したのち終了ボタンを押す。
↓
今まで開発してきた.hと.cpp及びresourceとして使っていた.objの全てを、Finder上でプロジェクトのフォルダに加える。(.proと同じ階層)(M‌​akefileは含めない)

この時点でQt Creator上に加えたファイルが表示されません。なにか設定が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: QtCreatorやIDE自体の入門書というのはないと思います。入門書を読んで解決するとも限らないので、トラブルの内容を詳しく書いて解決方法を直接質問してください。

Comment: お返事ありがというございます。
辿った手順を書いていきます。

新しいプロジェクトを作成
→
他のプロジェクト&empty qmake Projectを選択
→
ディレクトリを指定したのちDesktop Qt 5.4.2 clang 64bitにだけチェックを入れて続きをクリック
→
バージョン管理システムに追加でGitを選択したのち終了ボタンを押す。
→
今まで開発してきた.hと.cpp及びresourceとして使っていた.objの全てを、Finder上でプロジェクトのフォルダに加える。(.proと同じ階層)(Makefileは含めない)

この時点でQt Creator上に加えたファイルが表示されません。なにか設定が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントに書くのではなく質問を編集してください。

Comment: すみません。編集しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

1. ファイル -> ファイル/プロジェクトの新規作成
2. 非Qtプロジェクト -> C++プロジェクトを選択
3. （「完了」ボタンを押すまで同じ）
4. .proと同じ階層に.cppと.hをコピー
5. 左上のツリービューの「プロジェクト名 [master]」という項目を右クリック
6. 「既存のファイルを追加...」
7. コピーした.cppと.hをプロジェクトに追加する

Comment: ありがとうございます！うまく取り込めました！